# Userform Listbox populate and clear depending on selection from another listbox

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have 2 listboxes, lbA and lbB. I am populating lbA using SQL script which works fine. Now what i would like to do is when i select an item from lbA, lbB gets populated again from a SQL script. It works when selecting only one item from lbA but selecting two or more or unseleting an item then it either adds repeated items or doesnt delete items from lbB. I am puzzled as to how to approach this. Can anyone please help?

This is the code so far:

```
Private Sub lbA_Change() 
    Dim Num As Integer 
    Dim lngIndex As Long 

    If Me.lbA.ListIndex <> -1 Then 
        For lngIndex = 0 To lbA.ListCount - 1 
            If lbA.Selected(lngIndex) Then 


                Dim cnPubs As ADODB.Connection 
                Set cnPubs = New ADODB.Connection 
                Dim strConn As String 
                strConn = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;" 
                strConn = strConn & "DATA SOURCE=MSSQLSERVER2008;INITIAL CATALOG=MyDB;" 
                strConn = strConn & " INTEGRATED SECURITY=sspi;" 
                cnPubs.Open strConn 
                Dim rsPubs As ADODB.Recordset 
                Set rsPubs = New ADODB.Recordset 
                With rsPubs 
                    .ActiveConnection = cnPubs 
                    .Open "My SQl Statement" 
                End With 
                If rsPubs.EOF Or rsPubs.BOF Then 
                    Exit Sub 
                End If 
                rsPubs.MoveFirst 
                With Me.lbB 
                    .Clear 
                    Do 
                        .AddItem rsPubs![strName] 
                        rsPubs.MoveNext 
                    Loop Until rsPubs.EOF 
                End With 
                rsPubs.Close 

            End If 
        Next 
    End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to loop through the selected items in lbA and build up a SQL statement which can be used to populate lbB. Typically this would be something like `select fieldName from tablename where otherFieldName in('itemA', 'itemB', 'itemc')`  Right now you're running the query multiple times, clearing the listbox for each query: you need to take that part out of the loop which runs over the lbA items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a function like this to get the SQL statement.

```
Function GetSQLFromListbox(lbx As MSForms.ListBox)

    Dim i As Long
    Dim sIn As String

    If lbx.ListIndex <> -1 Then
        sIn = " WHERE field IN("
        For i = 0 To lbx.ListCount - 1
            If lbx.Selected(i) Then
                sIn = sIn & "'" & lbx.List(i) & "',"
            End If
        Next i
        sIn = Left$(sIn, Len(sIn) - 1) & ")"
    End If

    GetSQLFromListbox = "SELECT * FROM table" & sIn

End Function
```

It should return something like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field IN('2''3')
```

Then create a recordset from that statement and loop through it to fill the second listbox.  Note that if nothing is selected, it returns the SQL without a WHERE clause, so you'd get everything.  You might need to adjust that to suit your situation.

Comment: Thanks Dick. When i try create the recordset using  `With rsPubs
    .ActiveConnection = cnPubs
    .Open GetSQLFromListboxStatement 
End With` but get error Argument are of wrong type, are out of acceptable range or are in conflict with one another.

Comment: That was my bad. Its OK now.However, when populating the lbB, selecting two or more items from lbA or de-seleting an item should in theory display all items or take away items respectively in lbB. But it doesnt, it duplicates all the items in lbB. This is the code that populates lbB `If rsPubs.EOF Or rsPubs.BOF Then
Exit Sub
End If
rsPubs.MoveFirst
With Me.lbB
    .ColumnCount = 2
    .ColumnWidths = "18;6"
    Do Until rsPubs.EOF
    Num = Num + 1
    .AddItem
    .List(Num - 1, 0) = intItemNumber
    .List(Num - 1, 1) = rsPubs![strName]
    rsPubs.MoveNext
    Loop
End With`

Comment: Clear the listbox before each run. `Me.lbB.Clear`

Comment: Thanks again. It works but when de-selecting all items from lbA, then the previous selected items populated in lbB still there. How can i clear lbB if nothing is selected?

Comment: OK, I get it now.  I assume you did something like If ListIndex = -1 then clear it, populate it.  Glad you got it sorted.